# ReactJS: Can we have two onChange in a Single Textfield?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I was wondering if we can have two onCHange in a single Textfield.
Here in my code "onChange={ showDiv}" is a handler whose job is to show "<option value={"option2"}>Direct 2" upon click and hide on clicking option1.

and onChange={(e) => exhandleChange(e)} is doing some other task.

```
         <TextField
            id="outlined-select-currency-native"
            select
            onChange={ showDiv}
            SelectProps={{
              native: true,
            }}
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            name="Type"
            onChange={(e) => exhandleChange(e)}
            value={values.Type}
          >
            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
            <option value={"option1"}>Direct</option>
            <option value={"option2"}>Direct 2</option>
          </TextField>
```

Comment: What you should do, is have a single change handler, that combines both the stuff you want to do on the onchange event. ```handleChange() =>{ // ...do shoDiw, // ...doExhandleChange, // ...etc  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have more than one prop of the same name, the last one always overrides the first ones. So the last onChange is the one that takes effect there.

Answer (score 1):

No, last `onChange` prop will override previous.

Comment: Yes... Now i knew it now

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way will be calling showDiv function in exhandleChange function. It will help you, otherways it is not neccesary to have more than one event if you can do all in one.

Comment: Yes..  i did that

Answer (score 1):

You can't, no; the second one wins. What you can do instead is have a single one that makes both calls:

```
<TextField
   id="outlined-select-currency-native"
   select
   onChange={e => { showDiv(e); exhandleChange(e); }}
   SelectProps={{
     native: true,
   }}
   fullWidth
   variant="outlined"
   name="Type"
   value={values.Type}
 >
   <option aria-label="None" value="" />
   <option value={"option1"}>Direct</option>
   <option value={"option2"}>Direct 2</option>
</TextField>
```

Comment: @PriyankDeepSingh If you find this or any other answers the most helpful to you, please accept it. Thanks.